# How to avoid create some attribute in controller's create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model like this:

```
class Url < ApplicationRecord
  validates ...
  before_create :generate_number

  def generate_number
    self.number = a random value
  end
end
```

and a `create()` method in controller:

```
def create
  @url = Url.new(url_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @url.save
      format.html { redirect_to @url, notice: 'Url was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @url }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @url.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My DB only have two fields: `given_url` and `number`. Now, when I go to the `new` page, there's 2 input form for `given_url` and `number`. But I want `number` take the value from `generate_number`, not from the form. How can I do that?

Or more specific, is there a way to make the `generate_number` method to overrides user's input after the app already receive value from user's input?

Comment: First you could remove the input from the form, if you are not interested in the user's input. Then you have to remove the field from the strong parameters whitelist. But actually: Since the `generate_number` is always called before create, it would override the user's input anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to make the generate_number method to overrides user's input after the app already receive value from user's input?

Comment: you can use `after_create` for that. every time you submit form user input is overrides with your random value `generate number`

Comment: I tried but it did not works

Comment: Over-riding a specific attribute should work using a before_save also. in the model. `before_save :override_number

def override_number
 self.number = <some random number here>
end`. Can you see if you are getting some errors or if some other code is getting executed. try using pry gem to debug

Comment: what's the error when you use `after_create` method ?

Comment: @AlokSwain: I got no error, it just the number field is empty after I hit create, no matter it is before_save or after_create in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply restrict the input from user by using strong params

```
def url_params
  params.require(:url).permit(:other, :params)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found a way to fix this. As @ts mentioned in the question's comment, I changed `before_create :generate_number` to `after_create :generate_number` and *added* `self.save` to the end of `generate_number` method:

```
def generate_number
  ...
  self.number = some number
  self.save
end
```